# Mongo Load function in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

wanted to load a existing js file and load it using the mongoclient created from require('mongodb').MongoClient

MongoClient.load('test.js') doesnot work. Is there a require module for this?

Comment: I don't think that this works at all. Where do have that from?

Comment: we were using c # driver for mongo and it stores guid as bindata.Now we want to use node to retrieve mongo.. and querying bindata on node mongo driver client does not work as BinData is undefined. I am thinking load https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js in monogclient.load() but doest not work. basically  i need to load this in mongoshell through node

Comment: Sorry, but it is totally unclear, what you want. Mongoshell, Mongoclient, nodejs all together makes no sense to me...

Comment: Can we use mongodb load function inside nodejs mongodb module?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, you cannot load a mongodb js file directly into nodejs. If you would paste some code excerpts I could give you a hint how to translate that.